# Setting cookies(where value contains =) in javascript not working

Tags: javascript, cookies

i am trying to set a cookie in javascript. Cookies key-value pair are separated by "=". And, Unfortunately my value has a '=' in it. And it messes up with the key/value of the cookie.

```
document.cookie = "xuser=a=qJUmLNoHmkdfdfdf;Domain=test.com";
```

The cookie that is created finally is 
**Key:** a
**Value:** qJUmLNoHmkdfdfdf

I have tried different formats like below using " and '. But didn't help.

```
document.cookie = "xuser='a=qJUmLNoHmkdfdfdf';Domain=test.com";
document.cookie = 'xuser="a=qJUmLNoHmkdfdfdf";Domain=test.com';
```

Comment: Consider using the HTML entity `&#61;` or some other placeholder for `=`. Then you can replace the placeholder with `=` whenever you need to use it in your code.

Comment: Thankyou @PeterOlson. That actually worked. Can u post it as an answer. So,  that i can mark it and up vote it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using an actual equal sign in the cookie, use a placeholder, such as the percent-encoding `%3F` or the HTML entity `&61;`, or whatever else you like.

Then the placeholder won't mess up the cookie, and you can replace the placeholder back to `=` whenever you need to use it in your code.